# How can I return the sum of things counted in xpath

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

```
for $b in doc ("courses.xml") //Course_Catalog/Department/Course
where count($b/Instructors/Lecturer)=0
return count($b)
```

This code returns the result: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1.  What I acutally want is all the ones to be added up to return the figure 10.

I would be grateful if somebody can tell me how to achieve this. Thank you in advance for any help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sum:

```
sum(
  for $b in doc ("courses.xml") //Course_Catalog/Department/Course
  where count($b/Instructors/Lecturer)=0
  return count($b)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a million BeniBela. I'm grateful to all of you who are helping novices like me.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need the *count* of all such elements.

**Use**:

```
count(doc ("courses.xml")//Course_Catalog/Department/Course[not(Instructors/Lecturer)])
```

Comment: @NinaC, You are welcome. I hope, you'll conclude that direct count is a shorter, more direct and efficient way of getting a cont of nodes, than summing N 1-s. :)